# Did the Battle of Red Cliffs take place on the border between Cao Cao and Liu Bei's territories?

Tags: warfare, battle, ancient-china, 3rd-century

In the YouTube video [Three Kingdoms - OverSimplified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26EivpCPHnQ), we have this depiction of [the Battle of Red Cliffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Red_Cliffs):

> [image: screenshot of Three Kingdoms - OverSimplified]

The video suggests the Battle of Red Cliffs (赤壁之战) takes place on the border between Cao Cao and Liu Bei's territories, with [Cao Cao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Cao) invading [Liu Bei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Bei)'s territory.  I was discussing this today with my [iTalki](https://www.italki.com/) teacher, and he seemed to think I was mistaken, and Cao Cao invaded [Sun Qian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Qian)'s territory (like [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Cao-Cao-attack-the-Wu-Kingdom-in-the-sea-during-the-Battle-of-Red-Cliffs-given-that-the-2-kingdoms-share-a-land-border)).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Red_Cliffs#Location) indicates the precise site of the battle is hard to confirm, since the region's geography has changed shape over time.

**Question**: Did the Battle of Red Cliffs take place on the border between Cao Cao and Liu Bei's territories?